# Optimize order by random() in table with lot of records

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to fetch one random result (from count results I choose only one based on some stuffs/ this cannot be on sql level choosing) which satisfies conditions, my query looks like

```
for p in session.query(PersonModel).filter(and_(PersonModel.age >25, PersonModel.gender == 1)).order_by(func.rand()).limit(count):
    # some calculations and return only one
```

Problem is that persons table is very big, over 300 000 records. Can I optimize this query on any way, but still to return random ?

Comment: Optimization strategies may depend on some specific feature of the underlying RDBMS. What driver are you using?

Comment: @PauloScardine MySQL is database, driver is installed by ython-mysqldb, mysqldb driver

Comment: unfortunately, random is slow for db query, as it has to generate 3*10**5 random values. see http://www.depesz.com/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/ for other strategies (Postgre, but seems aplicable to MySQL as well)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, order by random() generates a full table scan which is going to bad.

One option would be to choose a random starting point, then apply your criteria to try to find a random-ish result.

So something like:

```
start = random.randint(max_id)
for p in session.query(PersonModel).filter(id__gte=start).limit(count):
    # some calculations and return only one
```

You'll probably have to be pretty defensive about that, keep trying random starting positions till you find enough results to find a winner.